# Let $ \Omega _1, \Omega _2$ be domains and let $f:\Omega _1\rightarrow \Omega _2$ be biholomorphism. Is this $f$ an open function?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, open-map

Let $ \Omega _1, \Omega _2$ be domains and let $f:\Omega _1\rightarrow \Omega _2$ be biholomorphism. Is this $f$ an open function?

I want to show that $f$ is continuous, bijective, open to conclude that $ \Omega _1, \Omega _2$ are homeomorphic.

Continuity and bijectivity are obvious, but I guess $f$ has to be an open function as well.

But, to show that, I could not use the open mapping theorem which only shows that $f(U)\subseteq _{op}\mathbb{C}$ for every $U\subseteq _{op}\Omega _1$, which doesn't tell $f(U)\subseteq _{op}\Omega _2$.

I also tried picking one element $ z_0$ from $f(U)$ s.t $B(z_0,\varepsilon )\nsubseteq f(U)$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, but couldn't go any further.

Is $f$ really an open function? If so, how can I show this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A bi-holomorphic function is bi-continuous i.e a Homeomorphism. And a Homeomorphism is an open map. Use pre image of open set is open under continuous map.

Comment: $U\subset \Omega_1$ open, then under inverse map $g=f^{-1} $ the pre image $g^{-1}(U) \subset \Omega_2$ is open. Now, take pre image under $f$.

Comment: @S.G Ah, now it's clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: A holomorphic and non-constant map is open (on any “domain”).  This is a standard fact in complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by the classic [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) this holds. More trivially, a biholomorphic function has a continuous inverse (so is a homeomorphism) and is a fortiori open.